# is a call to create a new object instance considered pure or not?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

in functional programming terminology if I perform:

```
val a = new Client
val b = new Client
```

Is calling the above constructor twice considered a pure or a non pure function?

Comment: Hold on -- `calling the above constructor twice` is not a function of any kind, therefore it can neither be considered a pure function nor an impure function.  Can you rewrite the question to clarify what you're really asking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can substitute your two lines by:

```
val a = new Client
val b = a
```

without changing the whole program behavior, the object instantiation could be considered as pure ([referential transparency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_%28computer_science%29)).

It will fail if the `Client` constructor has any "observable" side effect, or if you use identity equality in the program.

Answer (score 4):

Generally memory allocation is not considered to be a side-effect and so a constructor call in itself is considered to be pure.

Although it could eventually cause your program to run out of memory, this isn't something you can really control as a programmer, so "purity" is generally considered on the assumption of infinite memory.

If your constructor itself has a side-effect, then calling it would not be pure.